# Test Framework quit unexpectedly - Junit - Intellij

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, spring-boot, junit4

I have a SpringBoot project and all the tests were running perfectly. But today Intellij started to present the error "Test framework quit unexpectedly".

What could it be?

1. I've tried reinstalling the IntelliJ IDEA
2. I switched from the Community version to Ultimate in an attempt to make extra settings.

Environment:

- Windows 10
- IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2 Build 171.4249.39

**idea.log** - *The last lines*:

```
2017-05-16 20:01:34,597 [3596101]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111/lib/tools.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar 
2017-05-16 20:01:34,681 [3596185]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". 
2017-05-16 20:01:34,681 [3596185]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
2017-05-16 20:01:34,682 [3596186]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details. 
2017-05-16 20:04:23,492 [3764996]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Terminating: 17210/Maven3ServerImpl69bd6bce 
2017-05-16 20:04:23,542 [3765046]   INFO - stubs.SerializationManagerImpl - START StubSerializationManager SHUTDOWN 
2017-05-16 20:04:23,543 [3765047]   INFO - stubs.SerializationManagerImpl - END StubSerializationManager SHUTDOWN 
2017-05-16 20:04:23,544 [3765048]   INFO - org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServer - web server stopped 
2017-05-16 20:04:23,552 [3765056]   INFO - Types.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl - FileTypeManager: 242 auto-detected files
Elapsed time on auto-detect: 25584 ms 
2017-05-16 20:04:23,574 [3765078]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Watcher terminated with exit code 0 
2017-05-16 20:04:23,575 [3765079]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - START INDEX SHUTDOWN 
2017-05-16 20:04:23,921 [3765425]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - END INDEX SHUTDOWN 
2017-05-16 20:04:23,937 [3765441]   INFO - newvfs.persistent.PersistentFS - VFS dispose started 
2017-05-16 20:04:24,078 [3765582]   INFO - newvfs.persistent.PersistentFS - VFS dispose completed 
2017-05-16 20:04:24,085 [3765589]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE SHUTDOWN ------------------------------------------------------ 
2017-05-16 20:04:24,092 [3765596]   INFO - org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServer - web server stopped
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>br.com.e2pd</groupId>
<artifactId>controle-processos</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<description>Controle de processos para advogados</description>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <jjwt.version>0.7.0</jjwt.version>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <findbugs-maven-plugin.version>3.0.4</findbugs-maven-plugin.version>
    <docker-maven-plugin.version>0.4.13</docker-maven-plugin.version>
    <commons-lang3-version>3.5</commons-lang3-version>
    <rest-assured-version>2.8.0</rest-assured-version>
    <spring-security-test-version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring-security-test-version>
    <jsonassert-version>1.5.0</jsonassert-version>
    <maven-failsafe-plugin-version>2.19.1</maven-failsafe-plugin-version>
    <springfox-swagger2-version>2.6.1</springfox-swagger2-version>
    <springfox-swagger-ui-version>2.6.1</springfox-swagger-ui-version>
    <caelum-stella-version>2.1.2</caelum-stella-version>

</properties>


<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.mobile</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-mobile-device</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-lang3-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>${rest-assured-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security-test-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
        <version>${jsonassert-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox-swagger2-version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox-swagger-ui-version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!--Dependencias do Stella https://github.com/caelum/caelum-stella/-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.com.caelum.stella</groupId>
        <artifactId>caelum-stella-core</artifactId>
        <version>${caelum-stella-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.com.caelum.stella</groupId>
        <artifactId>caelum-stella-bean-validation</artifactId>
        <version>${caelum-stella-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.com.caelum.stella</groupId>
        <artifactId>caelum-stella-hibernate-user-types</artifactId>
        <version>${caelum-stella-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.com.caelum.stella</groupId>
        <artifactId>caelum-stella-boleto</artifactId>
        <version>${caelum-stella-version}</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-failsafe-plugin-version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>verify</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${docker-maven-plugin.version}</version>

            <configuration>
                <imageName>e2pd/controle-processos</imageName>
                <baseImage>openjdk:8</baseImage>
                <imageTags>
                    <imageTag>${project.version}</imageTag>
                    <imageTag>latest</imageTag>
                </imageTags>

                <entryPoint>["java", "-jar", "/${project.build.finalName}.jar"]</entryPoint>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>

                <serverId>docker-hub</serverId>
                <registryUrl>https://index.docker.io/v1/</registryUrl>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

I tried the command **mvn clean verify**, the test is running and the output is:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:16 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-16T21:02:13-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 86M/717M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.19.1:integration-test (default) on project controle-processos: Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.19.1:integration-test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: br/com/e2pd/exceptions/BairroException
[ERROR] at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
[ERROR] at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
[ERROR] at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
[ERROR] at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.tryGetMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:61)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.isSuiteOnly(JUnit3TestChecker.java:64)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.isValidJUnit3Test(JUnit3TestChecker.java:59)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.accept(JUnit3TestChecker.java:54)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4TestChecker.accept(JUnit4TestChecker.java:52)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultScanResult.applyFilter(DefaultScanResult.java:98)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.scanClassPath(JUnit4Provider.java:311)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.setTestsToRun(JUnit4Provider.java:191)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:134)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.com.e2pd.exceptions.BairroException
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[ERROR] at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[ERROR] ... 17 more
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
2017-05-16 21:02:13 - Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@24bdd5bc: startup date [Tue May 16 21:01:45 BRT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-16 21:02:13 - Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
2017-05-16 21:02:13 - Stopping beans in phase 0
2017-05-16 21:02:13 - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-05-16 21:02:13 - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

Comment: Can you post the full exception from the run console?

Comment: There's no console message.

Comment: Anything in [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085)?

Comment: I just tried to run on eclipse and I had the same problem. Nothing happens. The test not running.

Comment: Could be some antivirus/firewall blocking/killing the process. Anything in Windows Event Log? Any crash logs?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I just put the idea.log last lines.

About the antivirus/firewall blocking/killing the process I don't think so thats the problem. When I create a new SpringBoot project all tests is running ok.

Comment: Can you try running the tests from the command line using Maven/Gradle, depending on what your project is based on?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I just edited the post with maven output.